# Jsonb function works through pgAdmin but won't work through Npgsql in C#

Tags: npgsql

I need to do an update in a jsonb field in one of my tables, which I can do successfully through the following command:

```
update tab set draft = jsonb_set(draft, '{ result }', jsonb '"yes"', true) WHERE id=...
```

which updates the jsonb column to {"result": "yes"}.

When I try to call the following code in C#, there is no error, but the row is not updated.

```
string query = "update tab set  draft=jsonb_set(draft, '{ result }', jsonb '\"yes\"', true) WHERE id=@uid;";
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, pgsqlConnection))
{
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uid", 1);
      var ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

I'd really appreciate any insight on why this fails to update the the table.

Npgsql version is v6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure Json.NET Type plugin before use, like this:

```
using Npgsql;

// Place this at the beginning of your program to use Json.NET everywhere (recommended)
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseJsonNet();

// Or to temporarily use JsonNet on a single connection only:
conn.TypeMapper.UseJsonNet();
```

For more details, see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/jsonnet.html